# "Alan Smithee" equivalent for musicians

Tags: history, unknown-performer

Film directors use the pseudonym [Alan Smithee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Smithee) with projects they don't want to be associated with and recognized.

Is there an equivalent pseudonym for professional musicians who don't want to publicly appear on projects they consider too bad for their reputation or for contract reasons?

Comment: Looks like there may be many such aliases, for example, the name [Paul Procopolis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Procopolis) was used for various classical pianists on Saga records' ['Best Loved Gems of Piano Music'](http://www.musicweb-international.com/classrev/2007/Feb07/saga_remembered.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Dale Nixon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dale_Nixon) is an alias that was first use by Greg Ginn when he recorded the Bass on the album [*My War*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Black-Flag-My-War/release/717887) by the band Black Flag.

Then it has been used by:

- Brian Baker, when recording [*Four on the Floor*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Dag-Nasty-Four-On-The-Floor/release/892811) with Dag Nasty, because he was under contract to another record label at the time.
- Dave Grohl, when recording [*King Buzzo*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Melvins-King-Buzzo/release/409232) with The Melvins.
- Kurt Ballou, when playing Toy Drums in the album [*Board Up the House*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Genghis-Tron-Board-Up-The-House/release/1295666) for Genghis Tron.
- Ryan Adams as the bass player in his own project [*Orion*](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Orion-Orion/release/2304563).

As the wikipedia article says, it is often use

> usually to appear on albums without being in breach of record label contracts that stipulate label exclusivity.